# Use environment Variable in Json file on Cypress

Tags: environment-variables, cypress

I'm wondering if there is way to use a environment variable?

I export this variable:

```
export CYPRESS_USER_ID='UserID'
```

And I want to  see it here in my config file (dev.json):

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://url.com",
    "viewportWidth": 1280,
    "viewportHeight": 720,
    "env": {
        "UserID": "${CYPRESS_USER_ID}",
        "environment": "dev"      
    }    
  }
```

I'm running my test as this way:

```
npx cypress open --env configFile=dev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should understand that OS level variables prefixed `CYPRESS_` and `env` sections of config.json are ***alternative*** ways to set the variable.

Both ways will result in your test having access to the variable via `Cypress.env()`, either `Cypress.env('USER_ID')` or `Cypress.env('UserID')`.

In other words,  there is no point in trying to "see" `CYPRESS_USER_ID` in dev.json, it really does nothing extra from the test point of view.

If you want to change the key from `USER_ID` to `UserID` you can do it in the support file

```js
const osLevelUserId = Cypress.env('USER_ID')
if (osLevelUserId) {
  Cypress.env('UserID', osLevelUserId)
}

// or 

Cypress.env('UserID', Cypress.env('USER_ID') || Cypress.env('UserID'))
```

This would allow a default value in dev.json and optional override at the OS level.